# Syntax error near unexpected token ('

Tags: bash, syntax

Please somebody inspect my code to see why I get

> syntax error near unexpected token `('`

I have been running this code several time but all I get the same error

```
#!/bin/bash
vcf_file_dir="/10/"
project_output_path="$(pwd)"
my_samples_list=("1002793")  # Add your actual sample IDs

for sample_id in "${my_samples_list[@]}"; do

    # Print the sample you're retrieving data for
    echo "Retrieving file for sample: ${sample_id}"

    # Create a command to get the VCF header and save it to header.txt
    my_command="bcftools view -h ${vcf_file_dir}/${sample_id}_file.vcf > header.txt"

    # Launch the job with needed input files and command
    dx run swiss-army-knife \
        -iin="${vcf_file_dir}/${sample_id}_.vcf.gz" \
        -iin="${vcf_file_dir}/${sample_id}_.vcf.gz.tbi" \
        -icmd="${my_command}" \
        --tag "my_job_name_${sample_id}" \
        --instance-type "mem2_ssd1_v2_x64" \
        --destination="${project_output_path}" \
        --priority high \
        --yes \

done
```

Comment: How exactly do you run this code?

Comment: Try removing the quotes from here `project_output_path="$(pwd)"` so it becomes `project_output_path=$(pwd)`.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - it's probably the next line that causes the error :p

Comment: I run this as bash code.sh

Comment: How to get up and running debugging your bash code: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155551/how-to-debug-a-bash-script

Comment: I added set -x set +x to my code but nothing happened and I got the same line 69: syntax error near unexpected token `(' error

Comment: There isn't a line 69, so the code you're showing us isn't the code you're running. If this really is the code you're running then one of the custom commands such as `dx` is including or generating code that you haven't shown us

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what `dx run swiss-army-knife` does, but you're passing `-icmd="${my_command}"`, where `${my_command}` expands to a string, where the already expanded `${vcf_file_dir}` is. That contains `(VCFs)` and more.

From what you're trying to pass after `-icmd=`, I deduce it's supposed be shell code, like something `sh -c` would accept. If so, you need to build it with necessary quotes embedded in the code.

Specifically, what you're trying to pass is:

```
bcftools view -h mnt/project/Bulk/DRAGEN WGS/Whole genome variant call files (VCFs) (DRAGEN) [500k release]/10//1002793_file.vcf > header.txt
```

There are unquoted whitespaces, `(VCFs)` and `(DRAGEN)` look like subshells in unexpected places (this is where "unexpected token `(`" comes from) and `[500k release]` is a filename generation pattern. Proper quoting will fix this. Bash can quote for you.

> `${parameter@operator}`
> The expansion is either a transformation of the value of parameter or information about parameter itself, depending on the value of `operator`. Each `operator` is a single letter:
>
> […]
>
> `Q`
> The expansion is a string that is the value of parameter quoted in a format that can be reused as input.

<sup>([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html))</sup>

"Can be reused as input", I think this is exactly what you're trying to do. So where you build `my_command`, it should be:

```
my_command="bcftools view -h ${vcf_file_dir@Q}/${sample_id@Q}_file.vcf > header.txt"
```

Now if you do `printf '%s\n' "$my_command"` then you will see it's a properly quoted shell code.

`@Q` is a feature introduced in bash-4.4-alpha. Older versions of Bash can achieve similar results by using the `%q` format of `printf`:

```
my_command="bcftools view -h $(printf %q "$vcf_file_dir")/$(printf %q "$sample_id")_file.vcf > header.txt"
```

Maybe some very old versions of Bash contain `printf` builtin that does not recognize `%q`, I don't know. If this is a problem, try an external `printf` (like `/usr/bin/printf`). Only if this doesn't work, add single-quotes by hand. But note such naive fix will be safe only if the values of the variables are fully under your control and they don't contain single-quotes:

```
# FLAWED in general
my_command="bcftools view -h '${vcf_file_dir}/${sample_id}_file.vcf' > header.txt"
```

It seems the variables in question fulfill these requirements. However, in general if a rogue user or program could affect any of the variables, they could inject arbitrary shell code (e.g. see what would be the content of `$my_command` if the content of `$vcf_file_dir` was literally `'& rm -f important_file& '`). This is a flaw of adding single-quotes by hand. The method with `@Q` and the method with `printf %q` should be safe even in this case.

---

Side note: your code contains a shebang, but in a comment you admitted you run the code with `bash code.sh`. Be aware that the shebang does not matter when you run a script like this. The shebang would matter if you run `./code.sh` or so.

Comment: Thanks I get usr@LV19Y7325V Downloads % bash bash.sh
Retrieving file for sample: 1002793
bash.sh: line 12: bcftools view -h '${vcf_file_dir@Q}'/'${sample_id@Q}'_file.vcf > header.txt: bad substitution

Comment: @Zizogolu What is the output of `bash --version`?

Comment: @Zizogolu Alternative solutions added.